# Using 4th order Runge Kutta to solve the 2nd order differential equation of a damped oscillator

Tags: python, differential-equations, runge-kutta

So im tasked with using the 4th order Runge Kutta Meathod to solve the 2nd order differential equation of a damped occilator.

my function for the runge-kutta meathod looks as such

```
def RungeKutta(f,y0,x):
    y=np.zeros((len(x),len(y0)))
    y[0,:]=np.array(y0)
    h=x[1]-x[0]
    for i in range(0,len(x)-1):
        k1=h*np.array(f(y[i,:],x[i]))
        k2=h*np.array(f(y[i,:]+k1/2,x[i]+h/2))
        k3=h*np.array(f(y[i,:]+k2/2,x[i]+h/2))
        k4=h*np.array(f(y[i,:]+k3,x[i]+h))
        y[i+1,:]=y[i,:]+k1/6+k2/3+k3/3+k4/6
    return y
```

the rungeKutta function works fine, and I have tested it with a list of example inputs so that doesnt seem to be the problem

im given
[question parameters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2rUF2.png)
and have to make a class to solve the problem

```
class harmonicOscillator:
    def __init__(self,m,c,k):
        if((m>0) and ((type(m) == int) or (type(m) ==  float))):
            self.m = m 
        else:
            raise ValueError
        if((c>0) and ((type(c) == int) or (type(c) ==  float))):
            self.c = c
        else:
            raise ValueError
        if((k>0) and ((type(k) == int) or (type(k) ==  float))):
            self.k = k
        else:
            raise ValueError
    
    def period(self):
        self.T = 2 * np.pi * (self.m / self.k)**(0.5)
        return(self.T)

    def solve(self, func, y0):
        m = self.m
        c = self.c
        k = self.k
        T = self.T
        t = np.linspace(0,10*T,1000)
```

but im unsure where to really progress. ive tried turning the 2nd order differential equation into a lambda function like such

```
F = lambda X,t: [X[1], (-c) * X[1] + (-k) * X[0] + func(t)]
```

and then passing that into my RungeKutta function

```
result = RungeKutta(F, y0, t, func)
return(result)
```

but im not really well versed in lambda functions and am clearly going wrong somewhere.

an example input that it should pass would be something like this

```
####### example inputs #######
m=1
c=0.5
k=2
a = harmonicOscillator(m,c,k)
a.period()
x0 = [0,0]
tHO,xHO= a.solve(lambda t: omega0**2,x0)
```

would really appreciate some help. the requirments for the questions are that I have to use the above rungeKutta function, but im just kind of lost at this point
thanks.

Comment: A couple notes/questions: 1) class names are conventionally written in CamelCase in Python, so your class should be `HarmonicOscillator`, 2) why is `period` a method? Why not calculate the period once based on the fixed parameters of `m` and `k`, and set it in the constructor? 3) You can do type membership checks: `if (type(m) in (int, float)) and (m > 0)` to clean up your constructor a bit.

Comment: As far as addressing your question... what exactly *is* your question? When you say "clearly going wrong somewhere" what do you mean? Are you getting an error? If so, post the traceback (the entire error message). Are you getting incorrect results? If so, show how they differ from your expected results. Please also provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: i am trying to produce an array with a range of values so that i can graph the equation for the damped occilator, and i think this is the minimal reproducable example, i beleive theres a problem with the lambda function, however i have provided the minimal amount of other related code just incase the issue lies  there. Period is a method because the brief that ive been given to solve the problem required it to be.

Comment: Was your question answered? If so, please mark it as accepted so that your question can be removed from the unanswered queue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think there may be some confusion over the external forcing term and the Runge Kutta derivative helper function `F`. The `F` in RK4 returns the derivative `dX/dt` of the system of first order differential equations `X`. The forcing term in a damped oscillator is unfortunately also called `F` but it is a function of `t`.

One of your issues is that the arity (number of parameters) of your `RungeKutta()` function and your call to that function do not match: you tried to do `RungeKutta(F, y0, t, func)`, but the `RungeKutta()` function only takes arguments `(f, y0, x)` in that order.

In other words, the `f` parameter in your current `RungeKutta()` function should encapsulate the forcing function `F(t)`.

You can do this with helpers:

```py
# A constant function in your case, but this can be any function of `t`
def applied_force(t):
    # Note, you did not provide a value for `omega0`
    return omega0 ** 2

def rk_derivative_factory(c, k, F):
    return lambda X, t: np.array([X[1], -c * X[1] - k * X[0] + F(t)])
```

The `rk_derivative_factory()` is a function which takes a damping coefficient, a spring constant, and a forcing function `F(t)`, and *returns a function* which takes a system `X` and a time step `t` as arguments (because this is what is demanded of you by the implementation of `RungeKutta()`).

Then,

```py
omega0 = 0.234
m, c, k = 1, 0.25, 2
oscillator = HarmonicOscillator(m, c, k)

f = rk_derivative_factory(oscillator, applied_force)
x_osc = oscillator.solve(f, [1, 0])
```

Where `solve()` is defined like so:

```py
def solve(self, func, y0):
    t = np.linspace(0,10 * self.period(), 1000)
    return RungeKutta(f, y0, t)
```

As an aside, I strongly recommend being more consistent about your variable names. You named the initial state of your oscillator `x0`, and were passing it to `RungeKutta()` as the argument for the parameter `y0`, and the `x` parameter of `RungeKutta()` represents time... Gets pretty confusing.

### Full solution

Lastly, your implementation of RK4 wasn't quite correct, so I've fixed that and made some other slight improvements.

Note that one thing you might want to consider is making the `HarmonicOscillator.solve()` function take a solver. Then you could play around with different integrators.

```py
import numpy as np


def RungeKutta(f, y0, x):
    y = np.zeros((len(x), len(y0)))
    y[0, :] = np.array(y0)
    h = x[1] - x[0]
    for i in range(0, len(x) - 1):
        # Many slight changes below
        k1 = np.array(f(y[i, :], x[i]))
        k2 = np.array(f(y[i, :] + h * k1 / 2, x[i] + h / 2))
        k3 = np.array(f(y[i, :] + h * k2 / 2, x[i] + h / 2))
        k4 = np.array(f(y[i, :] + h * k3, x[i] + h))
        y[i + 1, :] = y[i, :] + (h / 6) * (k1 + 2 * k2 + 2 * k3 + k4)
    return y


# A constant function in your case, but this can be any function of `t`
def applied_force(t):
    # Note, you did not provide a value for `omega0`
    return omega0 ** 2


def rk_derivative_factory(osc, F):
    return lambda X, t: np.array([X[1], (F(t) - osc.c * X[1] - osc.k * X[0]) / osc.m])


class HarmonicOscillator:
    def __init__(self, m, c, k):
        if (type(m) in (int, float)) and (m > 0):
            self.m = m 
        else:
            raise ValueError("Parameter 'm' must be a positive number")
        if (type(c) in (int, float)) and (c > 0):
            self.c = c
        else:
            raise ValueError("Parameter 'c' must be a positive number")
        if (type(k) in (int, float)) and (k > 0):
            self.k = k 
        else:
            raise ValueError("Parameter 'k' must be a positive number")
        
        self.T = 2 * np.pi * (self.m / self.k)**(0.5)

    def period(self):
        return self.T

    def solve(self, func, y0):
        t = np.linspace(0, 10 * self.period(), 1000)
        return RungeKutta(func, y0, t)
```

Demo:

```py
import plotly.graph_objects as go

omega0 = 0.234
m, c, k = 1, 0.25, 2
oscillator = HarmonicOscillator(m, c, k)

f = rk_derivative_factory(oscillator, applied_force)
x_osc = oscillator.solve(f, [1, 0])

x, dx = x_osc.T
t = np.linspace(0, 10 * oscillator.period(), 1000)

fig = go.Figure(go.Scatter(x=t, y=x, name="x(t)"))
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=t, y=dx, name="x'(t)"))
```

Output:

[image: Runge Kutta demo]